# Add class for the_post_thumbnail_caption()

Tags: php, functions, css

How can I add a class for the function the_post_thumbnail_caption()?

When I check the caption in the front-end, it's just plain text, but I want to style it with CSS, so it needs a class.

Comment: Why not just use the function within a div with a class? eg. `<div class="caption"><?php the_post_thumbnail_caption(); ?></div>`.

Comment: That's it :-)))